# Django - How to get a list of queryset grouped by attribute value

Tags: django

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.type


#the type could be anything, its not predictable
MyObject.objects.create(type='a')
MyObject.objects.create(type='b')
MyObject.objects.create(type='c')
MyObject.objects.create(type='a')
```

Is it possible to retrieve a list of queryset grouped by the type like that:

```
[[<MyObject: a>, <MyObject: a>], [<MyObject: b>], [<MyObject: c>]]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's one possible way:

```
grouped = dict()
for obj in MyObject.objects.all():
    grouped.setdefault(obj.type, []).append(obj)
```

That will yield a dict like:

```
{'a': [<obj>, <obj>], 'b':[<obj>]}
```

Comment: You have saved me! I have been looking for something similar for a while! Why doesn't Django come with a function that does this out of the box?

Comment: That's a really cool trick.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need someting like **groupby** of [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

```
 from itertools import groupby

 data = MyObject.objects.all()

 [list(result) for key, result  in groupby(data, key=lambda item: item['type'])]
```

Comment: This should be `item.type`, not `item['type']` on the last line. It returns objects, not dicts.

Comment: `groupby` reports a new group whenever the key value changes, so you probably need to sort the items by type before grouping them.