# How to group by using django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to group by using Django.

I have three models as follows:

```
class Tutorial(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    tutorial = models.ForeignKey(Tutorial, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=False)

class Video(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    tutorial = models.ForeignKey(Tutorial, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=False, null=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=False, null=False)
```

In my view I have something as follows:

```
@login_required
def player(request):
    tutorial_id = request.POST.get('id', None)
    videos = Video.objects.filter(tutorial=tutorial_id).values("name", "category__name")
```

With that in `videos` I get:

```
[{'name': 'video1', 'category__name': 'category1'}, {'name': 'video2', 'category__name': 'category1'}, {'name': 'video4', 'category__name': 'category2'}]
```

But the result that I want is:

```
[
{'category': 'category1', 'videos': [{'name': 'video1}, {'name': 'video2'}]},
{'category': 'category2', 'videos': [{'name': 'video4}]},
]
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/28076330/492773 will help