# Django - Get queryset listing object attribute grouped by a different attribute

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Let's say I have this model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    SKU = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

and these values:

```
MyModel.objects.create(state='CA', SKU=1)
MyModel.objects.create(state='CA', SKU=2)
MyModel.objects.create(state='NY', SKU=3)
```

My goal is to create a dictionary which maps state to a list of SKUs for these objects. I attempted to do that like so:

```
my_objs = MyModel.objects.values('state', 'SKU')  # to prevent creation of python object on loop -- my real model has many more fields that I don't need to query
state_to_skus = dict()
for my_obj_dict in my_objs:
    state_to_skus.setdefault(my_obj_dict['state']).append(my_obj_dict['SKU'])
```

Which yields me:

```
{'CA': [1, 2], 'NY': [3]}
```

Which is exactly what I want, however, it does not scale how I would like it to when querying with almost 1 million entries. Is there a more efficient way to create this dict as a QuerySet to be something like this?

```
<QuerySet [{'state': 'CA', 'SKUs': [1,2]}, {'state': 'NY', 'SKUs': [3]}]>
```

I've also reviewed this question: [Django - How to get a list of queryset grouped by attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076222/django-how-to-get-a-list-of-queryset-grouped-by-attribute-value)
However, neither of those two answers are what I need; they still scale to the same complexity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of is to sort the records by state, and then use `itertools.groupby()` to group them by state. If you use [`QuerySet.iterator()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.iterator), then I think you can avoid having to load all 1 million records into memory. Adding an [index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#indexes) on the state field might improve the sorting time.

If you're still unhappy with the performance, I suggest you add a [minimal version](https://github.com/donkirkby/udjango/blob/master/udjango_models.py) of your model and query to the question, and explain what kind of performance you were hoping for.